# How to make angles around button like that?

Tags: html, css, sass, figure, angle

i need to make angles around the button.
I have tried made by ::after ::before, but i cant

Original: bottom of this site
https://kirarock.team/

[enter image description here][1]

my code is here
https://codepen.io/Artyom2022/pen/LYmoaOY

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0qgS.png
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, don't use an external source for that.

Comment: You can try to use the css clip-path property like the site you linked does, try to use F12 to analyze it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SCSS
for made angles i have used transform-origin;

```css
$clip_input: polygon(2% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 7% 100%);
$clip_submit: polygon(85% 0, 97% 51%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 3% 50%, 15% 0);
$border-color: #fff;
.form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 70px;
}
.button {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  &__wrapper {
    background-color: #00c9ff;
    clip-path: polygon(85% 0, 97% 51%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 3% 50%, 15% 0);
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;

    input {
      clip-path: polygon(85% 0, 97% 51%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 3% 50%, 15% 0);
      background-color: black;
      border: none;
      padding: 15px 57px;
      color: #00c9ff;
      font-weight: 100;
      font-size: 2rem;
      line-height: 130%;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 0.3em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: RobotoCondensed, sans-serif !important;

      .button:hover {
        background-color: #00c9ff;
        color: black;
      }
    }
  }

 span:first-child {
    margin-right: 25px;
    justify-self: end;
    top: 0;
    display: grid;

    &::before {
      transform-origin: bottom right;
      display: inline-block;
      content: '';
      background-color: #00C9FF;
      width: 1px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    &::after {
      transform-origin: top left;
      display: inline-block;
      content: '';
      background-color: #00C9FF;
      width: 1px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }

  span:last-child {
    margin-left: 25px;
    justify-self: start;
    top: 0;
    display: grid;

    &::before {
      transform-origin: bottom right;
      display: inline-block;
      content: '';
      background-color: #00C9FF;
      width: 1px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    &::after {
      transform-origin: top left;
      display: inline-block;
      content: '';
      background-color: #00C9FF;
      width: 1px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="button">
      <span></span>
      <div class="button__wrapper"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
      </div>
      <span></span>
 </div>
```